# Node author and body as plain text

Tags: theming

I need go get the node author as plain text and the same goes for the body field.  So that means **NO** html markup. I cant find the right answer on google for drupal fields.

```
<?php print $name); ?>
```

gives it with html...

Answer (score 0):

By the time that a `print $name` is available, you are already in a template or other late stage theme item, correct?  This means the parts have already been passed through render methods to add all that html.

When I had a project that created pdf reports for download and printing, removing these items was important.  I added a helper function to my site module. (every one of my sites receives a site_[name].module, but you could add this to your template.php if you want to keep this all in the theme)

```
define('UNWANTED_REPORT_TAGS', 'span/h1/h2/h3/h4/div/strong');
/*
 * helper function for removing html from report contents
 * Strip only selcted tags in THEME_preprocess_node function below
 * strip defined constant tags if none given
 * Growth order of O(n) where n is the number of tags, so defaults to O(7)
 */
function module_strip_only($str, $tags = NULL, $keep = TRUE) {
  if ($tags == NULL) {
    // load the defaults
    $tags = explode('/', UNWANTED_REPORT_TAGS);
  }
  if (!is_array($tags)) {
    // we were passed a string, check format and parse
    $tags = (strpos($str, '>') !== false ? explode('>', str_replace('<', '', $tags)) : array($tags));
    if (end($tags) == '') {
      array_pop($tags);
    }
  }
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    // tag by tag, strip our given string
    if( $keep ) {
      $str = preg_replace('#</?' . $tag . '[^>]*>#is', '', $str);
    } else {
      // we want the usual text, drop tags and what they wrap
      $cleaning = TRUE;
      while( $cleaning ) {
        // regex probably doesnt work here
        $clipFrom = strpos( $str, '<' . $tag );
        $clipTo = strpos( $str, '</' . $tag , $clipFrom );
        $clipTo = strpos( $str, '>' , $clipTo ); // find end of closing tag
        $str = substr($str, 0, $clipFrom) . substr( $str, $clipTo );
        if( substr_count ( $str, '<'. $tag) < 1 ) {
          $cleaning = FALSE;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $str;
}
```

The function will need an appropriate name for you, of course.  Then in your template file your line would be `<?php print html_strip_only($name); ?>`

If you just want to strip all `<>` sets from the string, you can do that like this.  `<?php print preg_replace('</?[^>]*>', '', $name); ?>` and I am dont think that `/` needs escaped, but if it does then it would be `\/`.  The online test tools want it escaped.

```
$pattern = '/<\\/?[^>]*>/';
$replacement = '';
$subject = '<p class="updated icon-clock">Updated: 1/14/2016</p><h3 class="field-label"> Related businesses  </h3>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
```